# Is there any advantage to using the program "Advanced Defrag" over the defrag capability in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, defragment

I followed the "Related Questions" link but "Advanced Defrag" was not mentioned.

If there are advantages, please list them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposedly it can fix registry errors, defrag in "real-time" (meaning that it constantly scans and defrags in the background), defragment USB flash drives (though this functionality is crap because flash drives don't need it), and runs faster than XPs build-in defrag.

Though there's nothing that [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner)+[Defraggler](http://www.piriform.com/defraggler) can't solve for 40 dollars less.

Comment: Thank you. It is available for free in North America today. I'm not sure about the rest of the world. I have posted the site where these things appear daily a few times and will not repeat it here unless someone requests it - I don't really want to be a shill.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [features](http://www.advanceddefrag.com/features.php) for it.